# How to send and receive data model object through Spring Integration message payload?

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I am trying to send a data model Java object to a Spring Integration Message Channel.  I have a jms outbound channel adapter.

Here is my Java code.  But it does not work.

```
@Autowired
MessageChannel outputChannel;

@Override 
public void sendToOutputQueue() 
{
    Record record = new Record();
    Record.setId("123456789");
    Record.setSerialNum("10000000");
    Record.setCode("ABC");


    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("record", record);

    outputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(map).build());

}
```

Here is my Spring Integration config

```
<int:channel id="outputChannel" />  

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundChannelAdapter" channel="outputChannel" jms-template="outputQueueJmsTemplate" />
```

Comment: What are symptoms you indicate as `does not work`? Maybe you have some error in logs? Maybe your `Record` is just not `Serializable`?

Comment: Do I need to make my Record serializable ?  Since HashMap is serializable by default, I thought I don't need to make Record serializable.

Comment: ??? That’s not how things work in Java. A map is just a container of references. Of course, keys and values must be Serializable to be able to be transferred into JMS Broker.

Comment: I made Record object serializable and passed the object to message payload without converting it to a Map. Now it can be sent successfully to MQ.

Comment: Please, don't duplicate comments for me. That sounds like a spam.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a `Map` into JMS using `JmsTemplate`, it is wrapped to the `MapMessage` (by default):

```
else if (object instanceof Map) {
    return createMessageForMap((Map<? ,?>) object, session);
}
```

And you has to be sure that all the key of the map are of `String` type and values are `primitivies`. That's according a `MapMessage` JavaDocs:

```
/** A {@code MapMessage} object is used to send a set of name-value pairs.
  * The names are {@code String} objects, and the values are primitive 
  * data types in the Java programming language. The names must have a value that
  * is not null, and not an empty string. The entries can be accessed 
  * sequentially or randomly by name. The order of the entries is undefined. 
  * {@code MapMessage} inherits from the {@code Message} interface
  * and adds a message body that contains a Map.
```

And here is a snippet from the ActiveMQ `MarshallingSupport`:

```
public static void marshalPrimitive(DataOutputStream out, Object value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
        marshalNull(out);
    } else if (value.getClass() == Boolean.class) {
        marshalBoolean(out, ((Boolean)value).booleanValue());
    } else if (value.getClass() == Byte.class) {
        marshalByte(out, ((Byte)value).byteValue());
    } else if (value.getClass() == Character.class) {
        marshalChar(out, ((Character)value).charValue());
    } else if (value.getClass() == Short.class) {
        marshalShort(out, ((Short)value).shortValue());
    } else if (value.getClass() == Integer.class) {
        marshalInt(out, ((Integer)value).intValue());
    } else if (value.getClass() == Long.class) {
        marshalLong(out, ((Long)value).longValue());
    } else if (value.getClass() == Float.class) {
        marshalFloat(out, ((Float)value).floatValue());
    } else if (value.getClass() == Double.class) {
        marshalDouble(out, ((Double)value).doubleValue());
    } else if (value.getClass() == byte[].class) {
        marshalByteArray(out, (byte[])value);
    } else if (value.getClass() == String.class) {
        marshalString(out, (String)value);
    } else  if (value.getClass() == UTF8Buffer.class) {
        marshalString(out, value.toString());
    } else if (value instanceof Map) {
        out.writeByte(MAP_TYPE);
        marshalPrimitiveMap((Map<String, Object>)value, out);
    } else if (value instanceof List) {
        out.writeByte(LIST_TYPE);
        marshalPrimitiveList((List<Object>)value, out);
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Object is not a primitive: " + value);
    }
}
```

So, your `Record` won't be accepted.

You need to consider do not use `Map` for JMS message and make your `Record` as `Serializable` to be able to send it over JMS. Or consider to use some other `MessageConverter`, not `SimpleMessageConverter` which is default. For example it seems for me a `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` should be good for you.

Comment: I made Record object serializable and then passed it directly into message payload without converting it to a Map.  It worked this way.   Now my problem moved to the receiving side. How do I retrieve it from Message as an object.  Do I need to write a converter to deserialize it into Record object ?

Comment: Not sure what is your concern, but the consumer is configured with the same `SimpleMessageConverter` as well. So, any `Serializable` should be handled as is.

Comment: I sent it like this outputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(paeRecord).build());And then receive it like this Record record = message.getPayload(); But I got exception saying Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.jms.JMSObjectMessage incompatible with com.noname.Record

Comment: outputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(record).build());

Comment: You need to show how you receive, but in your question, please. It’s not readable in the comments